# Vuetify suddenly shows different margin?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on a project. I started working on the project at a new location I noticed all margins are different! While the package.json are the same. so the only difference was the new `npm install`. For example `.row` class has `margin-right: -12px; marging-top:-12px` while on the other location it is `margin: -12px`.

I removed the `node_modules` folder at the first location and run `npm install`. Now the first location is exactly as the same as the seccond location with `marging` of all directions equal to `-12px`. But I believe marging of `.row` class must be zero at bottom and top.

why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like vuetify was updated. We just went through this same issue a few weeks ago. As there were breaking changes to `v-row` in Vuetify [Version 2.4.0](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.4.0)

We just removed all negative paddings/margins in our `v-row` tags and it solved the issue.

Another solution found on the [issues page](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12848#issuecomment-754694282)

```css
.row {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Here is a snippet from the [release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.4.0):

> v-row now has negative vertical margins in addition to the existing
> horizontal ones in order to fix spacing when grid components are
> nested (issue #11408). This change is known to cause layout problems
> in some cases but should be easy to fix. Discussion about this can be
> found in #12848.
>
> Workarounds for #11408 If you were applying your own negative margins
> or overriding the v-col padding you will need to remove these
> workarounds now that the bug has been fixed.